# Prove $Ker(\phi) =(x^2 +1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Consider $\phi: \mathbb{R}[x] \to \mathbb{C}$ by $\phi(f(x)) = f(i), \forall f(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$.

Prove that $Ker(\phi) =(x^2 +1)$, the ideal generated by $(x^2 + 1) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$

**Proof:** Ok, this proof is done like this:

To show that $(x^2 + 1) \subseteq ker(\phi)$

Let, $f(x) \in (x^2 + 1)$

Then, $\color{red}{f(x) = g(x)\cdot(x^2+1)}$, where $g(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$

Then, $\phi(f(x)) = \phi(g(x)\cdot(x^2+1)) = g(i)\cdot (i^2 + 1) = 0$

Thus, $f(x) \in ker(\phi)$

Hence, $(x^2 + 1) \subseteq ker(\phi)$

**Conversely**, let $a(x) \in ker(\phi)$

Then, using division algorithm we have,

$a(x) = (x^2 + 1)\cdot q(x) + r(x)$, where $q(x),r(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ such that $r(x) = 0$ or $deg(r(x)) \leq 2$

Then, $a(x) = (x^2 + 1) \cdot q(x) + r_{0} + r_{1}(x)$

Since, $\phi(a(x)) = 0$, we have, $r_{0} + r_{1}i = 0 \Rightarrow \color{red}{r_{0} = r_{1} = 0}$

Thus, $a(x) = (x^2 + 1)\cdot q(x) \in (x^2+1)$

Hence, $ker(\phi) \subseteq (x^2 + 1)$

Therefore, $ker(\phi) = (x^2 + 1)$

I am stuck in couple of places. And, here are my questions...

1. In $\color{red}{f(x) = g(x)\cdot(x^2+1)}$, why did we multiply $g(x)$ with $(x^2+1)$?
2. Why did we use division algorithm to prove the second part. Can't we just assume $\phi(a(x)) = 0$ from the definition of Kernel?
3. How did we get $\color{red}{r_{0} = r_{1} = 0}$?

Comment: **1.** Because $f\in(x^2+1)$, being in the generated by $x^2+1$ is being of the form $g(x)(x^2+1)$. 
**2.** We assume that, we assumed that $\phi(a(x))=0$. I don't get the question. 
**3.** You have a complex number on the left and a real number on the right, the real and imaginary part must be the same, hence the conclusion.

Comment: Hmm that makes sense. I was getting all messed up by trying to factor out what not.

Comment: For #2, I was saying since, $a(x) \in ker(\phi)$, can we then just assume $\phi(a(x)) = 0$?

Comment: Actually, that's the meaning of being in $Ker(\phi)$, that's the definition.

Comment: Oh Never mind. I think I got the point.

Comment: Because we want to prove that $a(x)$ have the form $q(x)(x^2+1)$. If we prove that it have this form, then $a(x)$ is in the ideal generated by $x^2+1$. Now, how are we going to obtain that factor? by division.

Comment: @MrSelberg Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Because $f\in (x^2+1)$; being in the generated by is being of the form $g(x)(x^2+1)$ for some polynomial $g(x)$.

**2.** Actually you are assuming that; $a(x)\in Ker(\phi)$ if and only if $\phi(a(x))=0$.

**3.** You have a complex number on the left and a real number on the right, the real and imaginary part must be the same, hence the conclusion.